# battery backup switching

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, battery-operated

I am working on an appliance project in which I have been tasked with the design of the power supply. The project specifications hold that from a 230v 50Hz wall supply two voltage rails of 5v (for small dc motors and some ICs) and 3.3v (for micro controllers) are to be supplied to other subsystems. In addition the power subsystem will need to keep a small fully charged battery and be able to detect when mains power is cut and supply the 5v and 3.3v rails from the battery instead. The aim of the project is to do as much of the design with discrete components where possible without being unreasonable (i.e we are allowed to use ICs if it would prove unnecessarily difficult to implement with discrete components.)

I began with a full bridge rectifier to step down 230v wall supply to 12v. 
[image: Full bridge rectifier]

I also found this circuit that makes use of transistors to replace a regulator IC. I was thinking of repeating this circuit twice with different values of the variable resistor (which is R4 in the circuit) in each to adjust the output to the desired 5v and 3.3v from 12v.

[image]

I'm now trying to figure out the best way to implement the backup system. I was thinking of using a LiPo 1000 mAh 7.4V battery (https://www.robotics.org.za/603450?search=lipo) together with a charging IC to charge the circuit and then use the same regulator circuits to get 3.3v and 5v. The problem with this is that that R4 resistor is tweaked for a 12v input and not a 7.4v (which would of course get less as the charge dies). I'm not sure what the best approach would be in terms of the regulators although I would like to keep these as low level as possible rather than buying ICs off the shelf.

I will obviously need a way to detect when mains power is cut but I also need to be able to charge the battery from mains when it is connected. I am a very inexperienced designer and so any tips or pointers in the right direction on the best way to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should do a thorough search on here - this type of question has been asked, and answered, more than once on here recently.

Comment: Perhaps. I posted because the ones i saw did not address how to charge the battery from the mains and do the switch over, they assumed that the two circuits were completely separate.

Comment: Why would you want to build your own regulators when they are so small and cheap off the shelf? That decision makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Which "two circuits" are separate? I see an ac/dc supply, a LiPo charger, a 5V regulator and a 3.3V regulator. You really need to clarify what you are doing and why.

Comment: It makes no sense but the project requirement is that "complex design effort" be made. The Professor does not see the use of a regulator as a complex design effort and therefore off the shelf regulators cannot be used.

Comment: The posts that i saw made the assumption that the system drew power either from a battery (charged from a separate source other than the mains) or from the mains to 12v dc supply. I would like to charge my battery from the mains to 12v dc supply (achieved through the full bridge rectifier above). I would like to use the regulator circuit above to get 3.3v and 5v rails. These regulator circuits should either draw from the rectifier circuit if there is a mains voltage or they should draw from the battery if there is no mains voltage. I hope that clarifies the problem.

Comment: So this is a “homework” assignment as you mention the Professor assigning the parameters... this is an assignment designed to focus your brain on the elements of the course taught so far and get you to synthesize and build on the material. There are sufficient hints in the ones I have seen to give you some direction. Hopefully others will also recognise homework...

Comment: Since this is a homework problem we will expect you to do a substantial amount of research and work yourself. Try narrowing your question.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand this. I don't feel that I was specifically asking for solutions in my post or was unreasonable. I posted the work that I have done up to this point and merely asked for some guidance on general direction. A simple "you are not on the right track, rather consider this..." or "to do this you want to research using this type of circuit" would have been appreciated. I will look for help elsewhere.

Comment: @Blargian Don't be too easily put off.  People here are not unwilling to help, they just become weary of bad questions and have had the same problems with homework questions enough times that procedures were developed to ask and answer them without harming anyone's academic integrity.  If you keep learning little bits and improving your question from what you learn, you will almost certainly get a good answer.

Comment: I would suggest that aside from rereading all of the relevant course work, you start drawing a large flowchart of the circuit to get everything straight in your head.  Just boxes with arrows between them will do.  Then start replacing boxes and arrows with more in depth descriptions.  This helps me a lot when a project is a bit over my head as I start it.  [120V]->[3V+5V] becomes [120V]->[Xfrmr]->[Rectifier]->[Filter]->[~10-14VDC]->[3V Buck converter +5V Buck converter]